# Google Charts Visualization

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using google's api for producing stepped bar charts in an existing system.
It works. I am using PHP to echo onto the screen the script.

I was wondering if it were at all possible to hide the data that is in the script. What I mean is, if I view the page source, I obviously see the script with all the data in the rows.

I was wondering if there was a way to hide these rows as strange as that rquest sounds.

Thanks for any response, this is my first post so be kind please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Charts API looks a the client-side data, so you can't hide the data or Google will not find it and not render the graph.

The only alternative it to make the Graphs API call server-side using XMLHTTP then capture the result, save the image then serve up that image in the browser. Not for beginners.